# Wifi has stopped working on MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I have a MacBook Air Dual-Core Intel Core i5 running Darwin 21.1.0. I think it’s about 6-8 years old.

Today my Wifi stopped working. It comes up with an exclamation mark over the wifi symbol on the top toolbar. I removed the service in Network preferences but following this I now don’t have the option to add this service back.

I followed a couple of guides that told me to run Assist Me and to run it in Safe Mode using Ctrl D on start up but none of these exist/work.

I’ve now bought a Thunderbolt to Cat5 cable adapter but this doesn’t do anything when I connect it to my router… I don’t get an option to set up an Ethernet service.

Is my network card toast? Does anyone know a way I can determine this?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It would be better if we knew the precise model & installed OS [Darwin 21.1 should be Monterey 12.0.1 which very probably should be updated, it was buggy]. Use the  menu > About this Mac - it will contain the exact OS & model designation. Also, the exact cable adaptor you bought. BTW, safe mode is achieved by holding left Shift all the way until the desktop ot login screen is reached. There is no Ctrl/D startup option, see https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201255

Comment: Thanks - MacBook Air 2017 13", 1.8 GHz Dual Core Intel Core i5, 8GB 1600 MHz DDR3, macOS Monterey 12.0.1. I managed to get my ethernet to thunderbolt adapter working by doing a reset with it connected to my router and I'm doing an update as we speak.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the problem is on the mac and not on router side?

Comment: 100% sure - it won’t let me turn on wifi

Comment: Completed the update and it made no difference. I've attached an image of my current options in Network in my original post.